# How do you change the margins of months in Android's DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, margins, datepickerdialog

I have been having some layout issues with android's material [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html).  By default, the dialog looks like so: [Default Date Picker Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu61em.png)

When picking dates on the bottom, the selector circle is cut off by the next month.  I would like to increase the margins for each month so the selector circle is not cut off for bottom days, but I am unsure how to approach this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(view.getContext(), null, 2015, 10, 20).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```